# Downloading Quotes in CSV format from Yahoo Finance - Beta symbol?

Tags: beta, yahoo, quote, csv

By using `http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=STOCKNAME&f=`I am able to download a CSV file, does anyone know what the symbol for beta is? It should go after `&f=` e.g. the symbol for the stock name is `n` and it goes in as such: `http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=STOCKNAME&f=n`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I can download the file .csv, but no data in. Can you explain better how to use the link?

Comment: `http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=AAPL&f=sb1b2nx`

Comment: FWIW, [gummy-stuff.org](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) is a good reference for yahoo's csv api, but it doesn't include a tag for beta. :-(